# installing pyinstaller leads to exceptions

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.5

I'm trying to make an executable of a python script I'm working on. Wondering what I can fix here.

This is what I'm getting:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586] (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd c:\users\tom\pyinstaller

c:\Users\Tom\pyinstaller>pip install pyinstaller Collecting pyinstaller   Using cached PyInstaller-3.1.zip Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) Collecting pypiwin32 (from pyinstaller)   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/pypiwin32/   Using cached pypiwin32-219-cp35-none-win32.whl Installing collected packages: pypiwin32, pyinstaller Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\program files (x86)\python
3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)   File "c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,   File "c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs   File "c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)   File "c:\program files (x86)\python
3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,   File "c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)   File "c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)   File "c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python
3.5\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyWin32.chm'

c:\Users\Tom\pyinstaller>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

You did not run the command prompt with administrator privileges.

Open the start menu to search for `cmd` then press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` to launch the [command prompt elevated](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-in-windows-10/).